# How would I make a system for asset encryption and decryption in c#?

Tags: c#, game-engine, assets

I am creating a game engine. This game engine is for audio games, which are games for the blind. So far I have audio, window display and keyboard input. I would like to add asset encryption so I can secure my sounds. I want to have my own custom pack file with a custom header, and I want it to be where I can add files to the pack and use an internal file name, and when I need to extract a file, I can use that internal name to extract it and return an array of bytes with the file contents. How would I go about creating this type of system? I do not want someone to make it for me, I just need an overview of the steps involved so that I can begin creating it on my own.

I tried some examples online, and I thought they would work, but they did not do what I wanted. I also had other code in other languages, but I did not want to convert that code.

Comment: Do you have a system working without encryption now? If not, that's the best place to start. You can always add encryption later once you have a working baseline. You should know that if your client decrypts the data then anyone that wants to spend the effort can do so also.

Comment: I already have a system in place without decryption. What happens right now is that I would give it a path and it just loads the sound from the path. So if I wanted to load a sound from a folder called sounds, I would pass the name of the sound I want, so, "sounds/test.wav". I want to make it where I can encrypt the sounds and be able to just give the name of the file in the pack.